# python - pandas - O() Big O complexity of grouping and summing a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-complexity, big-o

**Does the grouping and summing increase the Big O complexity of a loop?**

Suppose the grouping and summing is a part of a n loop where the data frame is  refreshed with new numbers at every iteration.

The loop is already of O(n) complexity. Does the grouping and summing increase the complexity here?
 
 
There is an example

```
import pandas as pd

V=[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,), (6, 7, 8, 9, 10)]
A=['A','B','C','A','B']
T=[]
n=2

for k in xrange(n)

   df = pd.DataFrame({"class":A, "value":V[k]})

    S1=df[df["class"]=='A'].sum()["value"]
    S2=df[df["class"]=='B'].sum()["value"]
    S3=df[df["class"]=='C'].sum()["value"]  

    T[k]= 1* S1 + 2* S2 + 3* S3      


#---------------------------------------------------
#for example if k==0

df 
         class  value
     0     A      1
     1     B      2
     2     C      3
     3     A      4
     4     B      5

    df[df["class"]=='A'].sum()["value"]
    5
    df[df["class"]=='B'].sum()["value"]
    7
    df[df["class"]=='C'].sum()["value"]
    3
    T
    28
```

Comment: Check the implementation. It's hard to reason about complexity if you don't know the implementation. Though here you might try think about what `DataFrame.sum()` might do. How would _you_ implement a `sum()` method?

Comment: @ Christoph Terasa - lets say if pass the sums to variables and do some arithmetic with the variable something like  a* sum(A) + b* sum(B) + c * sum(C) in order to get a total value for each data frame.

Comment: what is wrong with the question to down-vote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything depends on the implementation of the sum (is it naive, does it cache things? do lazy evaluations?). But in general your loops complexity is:

```
O(N * comp(sum))
```

or more strictly

```
O(SUM_i comp(sum_i) )
```

Now, with naive implementation

```
comp(sum_i) = comp(sum) = O(K)
```

where `K` is number of elements in the container. Consequently whole loop is `O(NK)`

However, if the sum is always the same between calls (nothing changes in the structure) and you cache in between sum calls you get

```
comp(sum_1) = O(K)
comp(sum_i) = O(1)   i>1
```

thus the whole loop is `O(N+K)`, but since you are "refreshing data every iteration" this is not the case, yet you could still have a data structure which does incremental updates to sum (since if you modify a single row in the structure, the sum changes in a simple way). Then, you could have

```
comp(sum_i) = O(elements_modified_in_ith_iteration)
```

and then if you assume that you modify at most `M` elements in each iteration, and you have .sum operation which is aware of the updates you get `O(NM)`.

As far as I can tell pandas .sum is the naive method, thus it will have `O(NK)` complexity (assuming that your container has at most `K` elements). However, if your container grows, for example you add `D` elements in every iteration, then you get

```
comp(sum_i) = O(K + i*D)
```

and whole loop becomes

```
O(SUM_i comp(sum_i)) = O(N(K + D(N+1)/2))
```

which is quadratic in `N`.